# Using eval, parse and regular expression

Tags: r, regex, eval

I have stored pattern matching functions as strings
eg. `string <- "grepl('a',var1)"` for selecting rows of a data.table

In some cases i have to use metacharacters

```
dt<-data.table(var=c("a1b.c","a-b.c","a1b1c"))
dt[grepl("a.b\\.c",var),]
```

I don't understand what **"\"** especially **"\."** leads to in the `parse` function

finally

```
dt[eval(parse(text="grepl('a.b\\.c',var)")),] # won't work
```

even so

```
dt[eval(parse(text="grepl('a.b[.]c',var)")),] # will work
```

I want to understand what `parse` does exactly in case the metacharcter I have to use is e.g **"^"**.

Comment: It does work. Just add more backslashes `dt[eval(parse(text="grepl('a.b\\\\.c',var)")),] `. I'll close this as a duplicate of backslash replacement. Someone else can grill you on `evil(parse(...`

Comment: Thank you, great. So what happens to all those backslashes step by step? Are there certain metacharacters in the parse function? In this case "\" and "." and i have to use the backslash to keep those two characters?

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(365)`